# CircleCI1.0→2.0 GitHubを使ってアップデートする方法

Tags: github, circleci

CircleCI1.0→2.0へアップデートしなくてはならないみたいなのですが、やり方が不明です。
GitHubなど使ってできる方法があればご伝授いただけないでしょうか。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

```
version: 2
```

を `.circleci/config.yml` のトップに記述しましょう。そして、 `circleci config validate` が通るようにしましょう。 `circleci` のコマンドがローカルになければインストールしましょう。

#### circleci コマンドについて

CircleCI サービスには、ローカルでの開発を補助するためのツール、 `circleci` コマンドがあります。 https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/local-cli/

Heroku や AWS がそれぞれ `heroku` コマンドであったり `aws` コマンドを提供しているのと同じような形式です。

このツールにはいろいろな機能がありますが、その中に、 `.circleci/config.yml` の形式が正しいかどうかを確認する機能があります。具体的には `circleci config validate` です。 1.0 -> 2.0 ということで、もしかしたら、お使いの `.circleci/config.yml` は 1.0 でしか認識できない形式の yaml になっているかもしれません。

まずは `circleci config validate` でもって、少なくとも circleci (2.0) が認識する形式の yaml になるまでデバッグするのが良いと思います。 `circleci config validate` が成功するようになったら、実際に circleci 上で走らせるなどして、ビルドの結果を見てみて、正しい挙動でなければ修正をする、というようなことをやるのが良いかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。理解が難しく下記でよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: .circleci/config.yml　　に　version: 2　と記述する　　そして　＞ circleci config validate が通るようにしましょう。　　こちらの意味がわかりません。　さらに　＞circleci のコマンドがローカルになければインストールしましょう。　の意味もわかりません。　大変申し訳ありません。

Comment: @ゲスト circleci コマンドについて追記しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。大変ありがとうございます。　しかしまったく理解できません。。。涙　Githubで　/circle.yml　こちらのファイルを確認できるのですが、そこでなにかできませんでしょうか？　どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: @ゲスト そうだとすると、多分、一つテスト用のレポジトリを作成し、そこで簡単な circleci 2.0 ビルドを走らせてみると良いと思います。 github のアカウントがあれば無料でできるはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。　はい、走らせました。　それでErrorが出て止まっています。

Comment: 解決いたしました。　スペースがないというErrorであることを教えていただきました。ありがとうございました。